# 'singular' vs 'plural' subjects with "no"

Tags: grammar, nouns

Should I use plural or singular nouns with ***no*** in the following context? What's the difference between the following sentences? Are both of the following sentences grammatical?

1- No ***engineer*** can do what he can do.

2- No ***engineers*** can do what he can do.

Note that the person referred to here as he is not an engineer. And I want to say that ***He can do something that engineers can't do.***

Comment: In my opinion, both are grammatical, but the meaning is different. The 1 means "any engineer(any one)cannot do what he can do", but the 2 means "any engineers(any group of engineers) cannot do what he can do. Don't trust my comment; I am not a native speaker.

Comment: @EvaristeGalois Thank you. As you have said I will wait for somebody who knows the language well. But it doesn't matter if he is a native speaker or not. Actually, my grammar book says "no" can be used with both singular and plural subjects but I can't decide how I should choose between them. So I have asked this qiestion and the example sentences are my own.

Comment: I have asked a native speaker about it. She said "The main difference between those two sentences is that one implies that whatever it is can be done by a single person while the other – er, well, what does the other imply? It has had an arbitrary ‘s’ added that makes it unidiomatic and therefore less clear. If you wanted to make engineers plural, a more natural way to phrase it would be: Engineers can’t do what he can do."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct but they mean slightly different things - or at least the nuance is different.

No 1 means that nobody who is an engineer can perform the task.

You might say for example: 
*By squeezing through the small hole in the wall to save the child she accomplished what no fireman could do.*

What you are saying is that somebody did something that would be impossible for a particular class of people, whether engineers, pilots or whatever.

No 2 means that no engineers from a set or group of engineers are capable of performing the task.

You might say, for example:

*We need to fix the crane before work can proceed but no engineers on site have the necessary training.*

So it's really a matter of context as to whether you prefer the singular or the plural.